# Changing OVRPlayer camera in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus

Background:
I have 3 Oculus OVRPlayerControllers between which I'd like to move. OVRPlayers are loaded from stack by timer e.g after every 10 seconds new player is loaded and the old one is `SetActive(false)`.

I have two possible solutions:

```
//1. Changing tag to MainCamera

    player = Instantiate(resource) as GameObject;
    player.SetActive(true);
    player.tag = "MainCamera";

//2. Enabling new Cameras and disabling old Cameras by loop

    oldPlayer.tag = "Untagged";
    oldPlayer.SetActive(false);
    //New player loaded from prefab and then->
    Camera[] cameras = player.GetComponentsInChildren<Camera> ();
    foreach(Camera cam in cameras){
       cam.enabled = false;
    }
```

But none of them work. New character controller is loaded correctly and IO works fine but camera is inactive just a black view. 
Any ideas how to reassign OVRPlayer cameras?

EDIT:
Unity registers first OVRPlayer as main or something similar because later when I manually re-enable it in editor I can use it game view also. But I need to redefine this "main or something similar".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it be adding and removing scripts from one OVRPlayer. This added unnecessary code and look-ups, but unfortunately did not find a good way to switch players.